# Identifying a map in groovy

Tags: python, groovy

While porting over a code fragment from python I've stumbled over a trivial problem:

```
if isinstance(v['content'], dict):
```

What would be the most elegant way to port this over to groovy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` (see map-specific example [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections)), like this:

```
if (v['content'] instanceof java.util.map)
```